# Received fatal alert: protocol_version - when using SecureAS400 class

Tags: ibm-midrange

In one of our customer places, we are getting this "Received fatal alert: protocol_version" when using SecureAS400 class. These are the SSL ports we have opened in the application server 448,9475,9473,9476,9474 from which our application is running. for testing purposes, if we enable the non-SSL ports then the application is working fine with AS400 class.

We are using
new SecureAS400(IPAdress, Username, Password)
new AS400(IPAdress, Username, Password)

I have tried following JT400 version (JT400.731, JT400.78), IBM 7.3 version on AS400 server.

By reading the error message it seems an issue with the TLS version, but I am not too sure what needs to be checked on the AS400 application side as well as what needs to be done on my application side.

please help me on this issue.

With Thanks
Amjath

I want to know is this related to TLS version issue? How to check the required version information?

Comment: Edit your post to include the version of the IBM i are you connecting to and  what version of JT400 are you using.

Comment: I have added the version details of JT400 used

Comment: how about what version of IBM i are you connecting to?

Comment: they are using IBM 7.3 version on AS400 server

Comment: Hi @Charles, with the new version of JT400 also giving me the same error? in the App Server, TLS 1.0 & 1.1 are in a disabled state and 1.2 is enabled, is that anything I need to check on the AS400 server side?

Comment: What JDK are you using?  When do you get the error?  Is there any additional information in the exception?

Comment: JDK version is jdk-20_windows-x64_bin, There is no additional information available because we are using this component in our dot net application by converting the jar to dll using IKVMC (IKVM.Net). from Wireshark we can able to see it was using TLS 1.0 is there any way to change this?

Comment: From AS400 server-side TLS 1.2 & 1.3 is enabled and while connecting using netstat we can able to see we are connecting to 9475, 9476 but we are getting the same error (received fatal-alert:protocol_version), but the same binary is working fine with non-SSL port(8475,8476).

Comment: We have imported the certificate from the IBM server with a private key (pfx) and imported them into the application server as a Trusted root certificate. 

in AS400 for cipher they are using *USERDEF, We even changed that to default & checked but again we are getting the same error (received fatal-alert:protocol_version).

How to check the mismatch between Cipher suites and/or Signature algorithms?

Comment: You're going to need to ask the IKVMC folks.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a very old version of JT400.

Unless you are connecting to a very outdated version of IBM i, say v7r1 or prior, I would suggest [downloading an updated version](https://github.com/IBM/JTOpen) of JT400 per this table:

[image]

There were numerous changes including SSL and TLS deprecations and additions between 7.1 and 7.3.

Note the [breaking changes at 20.x](https://github.com/IBM/JTOpen#changes-in-version-20-and-newer)

> **Changes in Version 20 and Newer**   There are several key changes introduced into JTOpen starting with version 20.x. These differences
> warranted a significant version jump to differentiate from 11.x and
> earlier code streams. Key differences include:
>
> - Adoption of semantic versioning, based on the guidelines published at semver.org. In summary, JTOpen versions now consist of three
>   digits, x.y.z. This provides differentiation between bug fixes, new
>   features, and breaking changes.
> - Java 7 or later is required (breaking change).
> - Function signatures may be changed from previous versions, in an effort to add typesafety. Version 20 will remain source-compatible,
>   but may have binary incompatibility (breaking change).
> - Breaking changes may be introduced on major version upgrades. Some examples of breaking changes include:
> - - Newer minimum Java version requirements
> - - Changes in Java classes that require source modification or recompilation
> - - Dropped support for older releases of IBM i Note that Version 20 contains some breaking changes as documented here.
> - - Changes to code hosting location and support processes (see Migration to GitHub and Support information)
> - Immediate removal of several antiquated components of JTOpen, including
> - - JTOpenLite
> - - jt400Android
> - - jt400Micro
> - - jt400Proxy If you need these packages, please acquire older versions from the archive site on sourceforge (breaking change)
> - Publication of "native" form to Maven Central (see Download Information). This allows Maven-based applications running on IBM i to
>   take advantage of extra optimizations present in the operating system

**EDIT**
With the IBM i running 7.3 that is up to date on fixes, it should have TLS 1.3, 1.2, 1.1 and 1.0 available by default (sysval `QSSLPCL` == `*OPSYS`).

I'll point you to the IBM [docs for SSL/TLS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssltls-system-system-level-settings)

It's possible there's a mismatch between Cipher suites and/or Signature algorithms available between the IBM i and your JDK's implementation of JSSE.

Comment: Hi @Charles, with the new version of JT400 also giving me the same error? in the App Server, TLS 1.0 & 1.1 are in a disabled state and 1.2 is enabled, is that anything I need to check on the AS400 server side?

Comment: This there any other case in which I might receive this error (Received fatal alert: protocol_version) other than TLS version mismatch?

Comment: How to check the mismatch between Cipher suites and/or Signature algorithms?

Comment: How to check the mismatch between Cipher suites and/or Signature algorithms? @Charles

Comment: is that any open Java application to test the AS400 connectivity? just want to eliminate the issues related to environment and other things